# How to collect user entered variables for database storage

Tags: java, android

I am creating an application that will take user entered variables and have them (eventually) uploaded to a database. There are a series of activities that ask the user to enter various values. I do not know the best way to proceed with storing these variables.

Right now, I have set up a series of strings for each variable in this activity that I need to save.

```
String ePercent, eIntensity, pPercent, pIntensity;
```

Then, when the user presses the continue button to go to the next activity, I want to store these entered variables

```
bContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                eIntensity = eERHIntensity.getText().toString();
                ePercent = eERHPercent.getText().toString();
                pIntensity = ePRHIntensity.getText().toString();
                pPercent = ePRHPercent.getText().toString();

                Intent nextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TumorSize.class);
                startActivity(nextActivity);
        }
    });
```

What is the best route to take to now store these variables so that they will be available throughout the app session (they need to be used for a calculation in another activity later on), and then also be uploaded at some point to a database after said calculation is performed.

I have tried looking up various things "storing user entered variables", "saving values for another activity" but seem to lack some necessary vocabulary to find the answer.

Comment: I am unsure the best place to getText().toString, and placed that in the onClick as the fields would not be filled out before the user clicks this. Tips for cleaner code appreciated also. It should be noted that the user entered values are numbers, is string the best way to label them? Keeping in mind I need to perform mathematical operations with them later.

Comment: Search for "persistence" for Android. There are many ways going about storing your data; 1. SQLite Database on device. 2. Shared Preferences 3. Writing to a local file. Start here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage

Comment: Thank you @MDNaseemAshraf exactly where I need to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send that strings to next activity, you can use intent.putString() method and to get that strings on next activity, you should use getIntent.getStringExtra() method. I have given one example below for how to use intent for passing data from one activity to another:

In your first activity:

```
bContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            eIntensity = eERHIntensity.getText().toString();
            ePercent = eERHPercent.getText().toString();
            pIntensity = ePRHIntensity.getText().toString();
            pPercent = ePRHPercent.getText().toString();
            Intent nextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TumorSize.class);
            nextActivity.putString("eIntensity",eIntensity);
            nextActivity.putString("ePercent",ePercent);
            nextActivity.putString("pIntensity",pIntensity);
            nextActivity.putString("pPercent",pPercent);
            startActivity(nextActivity);
    }
});
```

In your second activity:

```
Intent intent = getintent();
String eIntensity = intent.getStringExtra("eIntensity");
String ePercent = intent.getStringExtra("ePercent");
String pIntensity = intent.getStringExtra("pIntensity");
String pPercent = intent.getStringExtra("pPercent");
```

From this way you can pass any data to next activity using intent. You can also use SharedPreferences. By using SharedPreferences you can get data from any activity of your project. Search on google for it.

Comment: Actually, having trouble with nextActivity.putString(), showing putString() as invalid.requiring savedinstancestate. Although you certainly covered my question exactly. Just need to get this to work, looks promising.

Comment: Yes but better if you use SharedPreferences instead of using intent for passing data to a few activities later

Comment: Thank you, I am looking into SharedPreferences now, will mark as answered as soon as I have enough rep!